# Advanced Custom Fields data from ancestor page

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to make ACF data available on child pages two levels under the parent. I have a solution for making it available to a child page:

```
if ( $post->post_parent ) {
      $headingFont = get_field('community_heading_font', $post->post_parent);
      $bodyFont = get_field('community_body_font', $post->post_parent);          
      $primaryColor = get_field('community_primary', $post->post_parent);
      $secondaryColor = get_field('community_secondary', $post->post_parent);
      $fifteenSecondaryColor = get_field('community_fifteen_secondary', $post->post_parent);
      $tertiaryColor = get_field('community_tertiary', $post->post_parent);
    }
```

However, this information isn't available once we're a level deeper. That is, the ACF field `'community_heading_font'` isn't available to the grandchild of the page originally providing data for that field.

I've tried `post->post_parent->post_parent`, and I've also tried to use `post->post_parent` on a variable:

```
    $parentPage = $post->post_parent;
    $grandparentPage = $parentPage->post_parent
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the $grandparentPage ID for use in your ACF functions, use the wp_get_post_parent_id() function.

```
$grandparentPage = wp_get_post_parent_id($post->post_parent);

$headingFont = get_field('community_heading_font', $grandparentPage);
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_parent_id